# SipService.createSession() returns null or SipRegistrationListener doesn't work

Tags: android, sip

I am developing an application that allows users to make sip calls.

I faced the situation when *SipRegistrationListener*'s are not being called.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("ru.tenet.sipclient.INCOMING_CALL");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
    sipManager.open(sipProfile, pendingIntent, null);
    sipManager.setRegistrationListener(sipProfile.getUriString(), new MySipRegistrationListener(sipCallbacks));
```

I run my application first time - it's ok. ***onRegistering*** and ***onRegistrationDone*** are called and I see SIP REGISTER packets.

But if I delete the application and install it again, these methods are not being called and there is no REGISTER packets..

Looks like a bug in SDK or Android OS. Because application works fine after device reboot.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You got the reason for this?

Comment: No, I just start use pjsip library for my purpose